# Problem in Dynamic linking on tcl library

Tags: c++, tcl

Hi All
I have linked Tcl and Tk statically as following while linking with
gcc 443
/xxx/tcl_libs/8.5.9/lib/libtk8.5.a /xxx/tcl_libs/8.5.9/lib/
libtcl8.5.a

but when i tried to link it dynamically as following
`-L/xxx/tcl_libs/8.5.9/lib/ -ltcl8.5 -L/xxx/tcl_libs/8.5.9/lib/ -ltk8.5`

I am getting following error

> `/tools/linux64/gcc-4.4.3/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/
>   4.4.3/../../../../x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/ld: tkMain.o: in
>   function main:../../..//tkMain.c:33: error: undefined reference to
>   'TclInitSubsystems'`

One point when i tried to link tcl static an tk dynamic it works. I
checked it by ldd.
Please help.

Comment: That's very odd. I can't find any reference to that function in the Tk 8.5.9 source tree (it's a Tcl library-internal function). Are you sure you're compiling the correct code?

Comment: Static linking is working fine

Comment: Static linking doesn't enforce privacy rules properly. The problem is that Tk _should not call that function directly_. The code you've compiled is not the code you're linking against. That's bad news.

Comment: tkMain.c:33 is a file in my application. Its not TK file.

Comment: Read about fvisibility in http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.2/gcc/Code-Gen-Options.html, visibility settings don't work when doind static linking, but do for dynamic

Answer (score 0):

Try moving them to /usr/lib to see if it is a path specification problem. If by doing so it works, you need to check how you are specifying ld paths.

Comment: My LD_LIBRARY_PATH included tcl_lib path